# How to select a column in SQL Server with a special character in the column name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table contain the '%' in the column title, and this cause problem when I do the select statement on that column (Find below for more details). Does anyone know how can I select that column by not keeping the original column title?

Example:

```
Table1
name  ref_no  tot_sales  %Phone
-------------------------------
Alan  1       1          100%
amy   2       1          50%
ken   3       4          30%
```

Script:

```
Select %Phone From Table1
```

Error Message :

> Incorrect syntax near phone

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may want to wrap your column name in square brackets to have your [identifier delimited](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027.aspx):

```
SELECT [%Phone] FROM Table1
```

If the `QUOTED_IDENTIFIER` option is set to ON, you can also use ANSI-SQL compliant double quotation marks to delimit identifiers:

```
SELECT "%Phone" FROM Table1
```

Comment: ...and communicate to others *never* to use unusual characters for table or column names.